# Have the terrorists ever traded hostages for land?

Tags: armed-conflict, russian-federation, terrorism, ukraine

On June 18, 2014, the "pro"-Russian terrorists in Ukraine have captured [Nadiya Savchenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadiya_Savchenko), Ukrainian pilot, and secretly transferred her across the state border to terrorist bases in Rostov, Russia and Voronezh, Russia.
Then subsequently they have transferred her to the main terrorist headquarters in Moscow, Russia.

Multiple attempts to free Savchenko, including [statements at UNSC](http://www.un.org/press/en/2015/sc11809.doc.htm), gave no result.

Recently, the Security Bureau of Ukraine has released the following statement:

> *Yuriy Tandyt, an adviser to the chief of the SBU Security Service of Ukraine, says that persons close to Russian President Vladimir Putin's circles proposed that captive Ukrainian pilot Nadia Savchenko **be exchanged for the so-called "Route from Rostov to Crimea"**.* — [UNIAN, Ukraine](http://www.unian.info/politics/1108150-sbu-russia-attempted-to-trade-savchenko-for-crimean-route.html)

The same news appeared also in official Russian news. Dmitry Peskov, the press-secretary of the President of Russia, said he "is not aware" such negotiations were held, but found only one "reason" why such negotiation is impossible: because "Crimea is part of the Russian Federation." — [TASS, Russia](http://tass.ru/en/russia/812670)

Note that the alleged negotiations haven't been about accepting the "Russian" status of the occupied Crimea, but about the **landline road** from Rostov, Russia, to the occupied Crimea. In exchange for freeing Savchenko and/or other hostages captured in Ukraine and now deterred on the Russia.

Regardless whether the alleged negotiations have been held or not, I can't recall of similar events occurred in the past. Hence, the question:

**Has it happened in the world's history when terrorists offered to exchange hostages for state's territory?** Regardless whether such attempt was successful or not.

Comment: I like the way you call the Russian's soldiers & politicians/KGB-agents terrorists ;)

Comment: @Quandary, Russian officials repeatedly declare that there are no Russian troops in Ukraine *(only their bodies return back to the Russia, yeah)*. OTOH, these people commit terrorist acts in Ukraine. Hence the most formal term, *terrorists*.

Comment: in Germany they are called separatists.

Comment: @bytebuster maybe I wrote it unclear, I meant that those people are called "seperatist" by the print media.  [Separatisten in der Ukraine](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/europa/ukraine-krise-warum-russen-die-separatisten-verehren-13078378.html), like in this article, but I did not interepret its correctness

Comment: @bytebuster separatist and terrorist are not mutually exclusive. One can be a separatist who engages in terrorism in an attempt to advance his separatist agenda.

Comment: I think the highly debatable prelude steals the focus from a good question.

Comment: I agree with @ugoren. The bulk of his post is not necessary to understand the question, and it almost looks like the question itself is just tacked on as an excuse to make this blog post.

Comment: Since when capturing hostile fighters is called terrorism?

Comment: @convert I'm not sure about where does your logic come from. The DPR/LPR have been widely recognized as terrorist organizations, even before the capture of Savchenko. The question is not about the fact of the capture, but about the attempted exchange of a hostage for territory.

Comment: @bytebuster Calling captured combatant a hostage is incorect, that´s what my coment was about.

Comment: @convert, in 2015, it was a police anti-terrorist operation (ATO). You may want to take a brief look at the Geneva Conventions of 1949 for a legal definition of what "combatant" is. If you shoot at, capture, or displace a police officer you can't claim you've been engaged in a combat.

Comment: @bytebuster It doesn´t meter how it was called, ukrainian army was used, which even violates ukrainian constitution. Calling an officer of ukrainian airforce a police officer sounds also strange.